# 500 error on fresh install of IIS and PHP

Tags: php, iis

When attempting to run a PHP file on Windows server 2012 and IIS, I keep getting a 500 error. I cannot find any detailed logs or anything. However, when going to PHP Manager for IIS and click check config, I get the following error:

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module    FastCgiModule 
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler    PHP55_via_FastCGI 
Error Code    0xc0000135 
Requested URL    http://domain.com:80/brkld3ip.php 
Physical Path    drive:\sites\domain.com\brkld3ip.php 
Logon Method    Anonymous 
Logon User    Anonymous
```

I installed PHP using Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0 on a fresh install of Windows Server.

I am new to IIS coming from Linux. So I am not "learned" enough in IIS to know what's going on.  I have tried updating C++ redistributable 2012 update 4 as a couple websites suggest. Anybody have any other ideas?

EDIT: Another thing I checked was memory limit. One site suggested my memory limit needed to be upped. No change.

EDIT: Question: Does Windows have to be rebooted for PHP changes to take effect?

Comment: Which version of PHP?

Comment: Well when i installed php 5.5 with that Microsoft installer it also installed 5.3.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's a fairly good chance you're missing the correct VC++ runtime for the version of PHP you're running.

If you're running PHP 5.5.x you need to ensure the VC++11 runtime is installed:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Make sure you download and install the x86 version (`vcredist_x86.exe`), PHP on Windows isn't 64 bit yet.

If you're running PHP 5.4.x then you need to install the VC++9 runtime:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582

Comment: You was correct. I already did the x64 since it was a 64 bit machine. Installed  the x86 and instantly (no reboot required) it started working. Thanks! I racked my brain for hours!

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed it immediately for me as well. +1

Comment: Thanks! PHP 5.6 instance requires VC++ 11  (VS 2012) runtimes

Comment: Thanks ! Originally missed the part about x86 but after failing miserably I saw what I missed and everything works fine now.

Comment: For anyone having this issue with **PHP 5.6**, you need the **x86** version of **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4** *(vcredist_x86.exe)*, which can be obtained from the following page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: @kev you're a life-saver. Fixed it immediately. I specifically created an account to leave this message to say thank you!

Comment: @pongba - glad I could help :)

Comment: Brilliant! saved my day!

Comment: Oh my God... 2 days.. I was almost getting crazy man... It was the 64 bit issue. As soon as I downloaded x86, it just worked.... THANKS

Comment: For PHP 7.2.x use VC++ 2015 with the correct bit version (x64, x86, depending on the bit version of PHP)

Comment: Granted it's 4 years later but the 64b version worked for me with the 64b PHP, just in case this helps anyone.

Comment: @mindmischief - thanks for that info. After four years I'm amazed those links still work :)

Comment: @derekmx271 Yupe that's right, php 5.6 requires VC++ 2012 x86. I have installed x64 but not the x86. ah~~~, have been trying to fix this the whole morning.

Answer (score 6):

I got caught out by a similar message, and it turned out that I had not installed the CGI Server Role (under IIS -> Application Development).

Comment: How similar is the message?

Comment: I installed the VC++ 11 runtime but I also had to install CGI support to get it working. On Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5. Find it under `Turn windows features on or off > Internet information services > application development features > CGI`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error for PHP 7.0.3 on a 2012 R2 server with IIS 8.5.

The solution is to install: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 32bits

Everything worked properly after installing this.

Answer (score 1):

Still had the 500 error after installing the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 32bits.

Ran procmon from microsoft sysinternals and when requesting my php web page found

```
w3wp.exe C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe "ACCESS DENIED"
```

w3wp.exe is the app pool running under IIS

Giving the specific app pool user READ/EXECUTE permissions to c:\php fixed the issue.