# ERROR 500 - Internal server error on PHP Sites

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, wordpress, 500-error

I am running IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. Over a month ago I did the generic installation of PHP (v5.5.11), MySQL and the phpMyAdmin interface and it all worked great. The other day I started playing with WordPress sites and it all got ugly. Now on any site that involves PHP I get either the "500 - Internal server error" (including phpMyAdmin) or the browser just sits there forever "loading" but not receiving any data as if it is still trying to resolve the URL.

I have tried installing the 32-bit version of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 as suggested here: 
[500 error on fresh install of IIS and PHP](https://serverfault.com/questions/613927/500-error-on-fresh-install-of-iis-and-php)

I have been tearing my hair out all day. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure where the default log file is in Windows, but with Apache in Linux the log file gives AWESOME insights directly after a page loads with a 500 error. Do you have any log file?

Comment: Either IIS manager or just c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I was able to find the log files but my untrained eye didnt see anything useful there. 

I remoted into the server and got the whole error message. See screenshot below:

[Screenshot](http://slehmann36.com/capture.png).

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Consider this thread regarding the web.config error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions